# CLMonitor exit codes

Tags: pvs-studio

Unfortunately, [documentation](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0031/) doesn't mention if CLMonitor utility exits with different codes (for example, to distinguish if errors were found after analysis or weren't).

Can anybody provide list of exit codes of CLMonitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CLMonitor does not provide a specific exit code for when the new messages are generated. The currently available exit codes, which are mostly service-specific, and not intended for 'general' use, are:

```
Success = 0,
GeneralException = 1,
GeneralPipeConnectionError = 2,
ServerAlreadyRunning = 3,
ServerIsNotRunning = 4,
ConnectionFault = 5,
IncorrectCMDArgument = 6,
NoAccessRights = 7,
NoTracedFiles = 8
```

You can determine whether the new warnings were generating by using [PlogConverter](https://github.com/viva64/PlogConverter-MSBuild-VS) tool on the generated analysis log (plog), by specifying the 'Totals' render type (which generates the numbers of analyzer messages in each of the analyzer's categories), and then parsing the resulting file.

Comment: I'm trying to determine (in cmd file) if CLMonitor couldn't perform analysis or did not found any problems. In both cases there will be no output file to convert by PlogConverter.

Comment: If CLMonitor finished the analysis successfully, its exit code should be zero. If there were some issues or exceptions during the analysis, the exit code will be set to one of the values I've listed above (most commonly, the 'General Exception' one, that is, '1'). So I think you can use exit code '0' to mark the successful analysis, and use the presence\generation of the log file to separate an analysis without any issues from when some issues are found by the analyzer.

Comment: Please also remember that if you've marked some of the analyzer messages as 'false positive' ones, the log will be generated, but these messages will be marked as 'false alarms' - you can use PlogConverter to filter-out these warnings.